# Reset Serial module annually

Tags: entities

I'm a newbie to drupal 7 for a year by now. I'm trying to make a unique id field that would increment per node of content type I create.

The **computed fields module** + **serial module** is the likeliest method accomplishing my goal, yet I'd like to restart the serial number starting each year, I'm totally lost, please help.

This is the code I've used.
The output: 20150001, 20150002 and so on.
Is there a method to restart the serial num. back to 0001 again when it's a new year?

- **Computed Code (PHP)**

  ```
  $entity_field[0]['value'] = $entity->field_serial[LANGUAGE_NONE][0]['value'];
  ```
- **Display Code (PHP)**

  ```
  $display_output = date('Y') . sprintf('%04s', substr(str_pad($entity_field_item['value'], 4, '0', STR_PAD_LEFT), -4, 4));
  ```

This is another method I've found, it works on the D6 website, but turns into a blank on my D7 published contents. It's from a field on D6 using **php filter module**.

```
<?php
$case_id_query=db_result(db_query("select  max(field_case_id_value) as id  from {content_field_case_id} "));

$case_id = date("Y") . sprintf ( '%04s', substr ( $case_id_query, 4, strlen ( $case_id_query ) - 4 ) + 1 );
return array(
  0 => array('value' =>$case_id),
); 
?>
```

can I transform the method above to D7?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I recommend in the future to peruse the Module issue queue. :)

There are a number of patches in the following issue thread, one of which I've used to reset yearly (and actually modified to reset monthly): https://www.drupal.org/node/2168071

Comment: Christian, thank you for your advise! I'll give it try and let you know the outcome.

Comment: It worked!! I've used the developing module version and updated the patch 29 into the revelvent files before installing. Now all I'll need to change is the digits. you've saved my day~ XD

Comment: Fantastic! I'm glad you're making progress! :)

As far as the digits go, how do you intend to make them look vs. how they're currently printed?

Comment: well, I've intended to cut down the digits of the "0"s after the year, which originally looks like "2015**000001**", I've cut down the numbers within the serial.inc file of the patch, resolving a "2015**0001**" as result.